# How do I request a read receipt when sending e-mail with Outlook for Mac 2011?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I've been using MAC OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5. How do I request a read receipt when sending e-mail with Outlook for Mac 2011?

Answer (score 2):

Outlook:Mac doesn't have the read receipt feature.

And, frankly, you shouldn't use read receipts.  Most mail clients can be set up to simply ignore read receipt requests.  If the mail client isn't ignoring read receipt requests, then it gives the reader a message asking if the reader wants to send a read receipt; many people select no.  The existence of a read receipt doesn't actually tell you whether your reader read your mail.

Comment: There may be specific reasons why Selahattin needs to request a read receipt. Why assume they are doing something wrong? "You shouldn't" isn't always true in this case. There's nothing dangerous, and there is have no reason to assume the Selahattin or anybody else is assuming anything about those read receipts.

Comment: Couldn't agree more about not using read receipts!  Here's the M$ question that says Outlook For Mac does not offer this option: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Can-I-request-a-read-receipt-in-Outlook-2016-for-Mac-2493ae0b-fba6-47f3-a5d5-ca0c0dbfe878

Answer (score 2):

To make Mac OS X Mail request a read receipt for every message you send:

1. Open Terminal and run the following command:

   ```
   defaults read com.apple.mail UserHeaders
   ```
2. If that command returns

   > The domain/default pair of (com.apple.mail, UserHeaders) does not exist

   run the following replacing `Name` with your name and `email@address` with your email address

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders '{"Disposition-Notification-To" = "Name <email@address>"; }'
   ```

   For example, the complete line could read

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders '{"Disposition-Notification-To" = "Heinz Tschabitscher <sender@example.com>"; }'"
   ```
3. If the "defaults read" command above returns a line of values that starts with `{` and ends in `}`:

   1. Highlight the entire line. It might read something like `{Bcc = "bcc@example.com"; }`, for example.
   2. Press Command-C.
   3. Type `defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders '`
   4. Press Command-V.
   5. Type `'`.
   6. Insert `"Disposition-Notification-To" = "Name <email@address>";` in front of the closing `}` character, replacing `Name` with your name and `email@address` with your email address.

      For example, the line might now read

      ```
      defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders '{Bcc = "bcc@example.com"; "Disposition-Notification-To" = "Heinz Tschabitscher <sender@example.com>"; }'
      ```
   7. Press Enter.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this is useful information, the question is specifically regarding making Outlook request a read receipt, not Mail.app.

Answer (score 0):

[Outlook for Mac does not support read-receipts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Can-I-request-a-read-receipt-in-Outlook-2016-for-Mac-2493ae0b-fba6-47f3-a5d5-ca0c0dbfe878)

Perhaps use your email provider's webmail application to request a read-receipt?

For Office 365, sign into https://portal.office.com, compose a message, click the ellipses to bring up message options, choose the "Show message options..." menu item, then click the "Request a read receipt".

Gmail might have a similar feature.

I personally NEVER request read-receipts.  Furthermore, when requested to send read-receipts I always refuse :)

Answer (score -2):

There is a new app that let you integrate read receipts in apple mail, both incoming and outgoing ones. Check http://www.ireceiptmail.com ;) It does not work with Outlook though...

Comment: Please see the help center regarding [self-promotion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and make sure you disclose if you are affiliated with a product.

Comment: How am I suppose to disclose my affiliation? Yes I am involved in the project.