# How to get read receipt with Outlook for Mac 2011 with more than one mail account?

Tags: macbook-pro, email, ms-office

Regarding [How do I request a read receipt when sending e-mail with Outlook for Mac 2011?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112110/how-do-i-request-a-read-receipt-when-sending-e-mail-with-outlook-for-mac-2011/141166#141166):

There is a solution which I havent applied yet because it seemed for a single account. Is it possible to go for these steps twice to get read receipt for two accounts, depending on which has sent the email?

Comment: I would simply add this as a comment but my rep points are not enough

Comment: That answer is for Mail.app, not Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

I think which the solution is emulate to [MailTrack.io](https://mailtrack.io)

i.e. add a invisible image hosted in cloud and to be verify if it was requested. But I don't know if it is posible in Outlook for Mac 2011.